# React best practice for passing props to children - pass all props, or explicitly pass selected props?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Which approach is better practice when passing props to child components:

**Approach 1**. Pass all `props` using `{...props}`, e.g.

```
ParentComponent = (props) => {
    return <ChildComponent {...props}> 
}
```

**Approach 2**. Explicitly pass only required `props`, e.g

```
ParentComponent = ({prop1, prop2}) => {
    return <ChildComponent prop1={prop1}, prop2={prop2}> 
}
```

**Approach 1**: causes warnings when illegal `props` are inadvertently passed to `children`, as described [here](https://reactjs.org/warnings/unknown-prop.html)

**Approach 2**: makes it a pain to propagate CSS styles down to `child components`, in cases where you want to style all instances of a reused component, since each CSS `style property` needs to be explicitly added to the set of `props` being passed down.

Comment: Why not both...

Comment: Do you find this case coming up often (where a parent component is passing on all or most of its props)? This may be an indication that you should use context instead of props, though without knowing the details of what you're using it for it's hard to give a specific recommendation.

Comment: In addition to using context, you can also look into component composition, where you would write the components as `<Parent propA={propA}><Child prop1={prop1} prop2={prop2}/></Parent>`. This way the props don't need to be passed through Parent to get to Child.

Comment: Great discussion here: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#before-you-use-context

Answer (score 1):

I would never use [prop drilling](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/prop-drilling/) it is very tricky and can make your app very slow. Use approach 2! :)